# Simple App Routing Flask

Tags: python, flask

Why does going to /uploads/stack1234 give me a 404 error?

```
filed  = "stack1234"
@app.route('/uploads/<filed>')
def stack():
    return render_template('filed.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

`stack()` has to have the argument defined. No need to define it as a global variable.

```
@app.route('/uploads/<filed>')
def stack(filed):
    return render_template('filed.html')
```

Comment: `filed` is constantly changing though? If one of the values of filed is "stack1234" shouldn't I be able to go to /uploads/stack1234

Comment: What was wrong about what I did? What you did doesn't work either btw.

Comment: The point of the routes is to do something with the values. What you have doesn't matter. Anything with /uploads/xxxx should match your route. If that still doesn't work I suspect you have other problems in the code that you haven't shown here.

Comment: In other words you need to do something with `filed` inside the function to display whatever it is you're trying to retrieve.

Comment: so if I did `print filed` instead of `return render_template('filed.html')` would you expect that to work? Because that doesn't work either.

Comment: Your thing makes no sense. Why does it need to be passed as an argument?

Comment: I suggest you read the getting started for Flask. It doesn't appear you understand the framework.